# Should I create a class to hold a http status code and endpoint data

Tags: java, java-8

I'm calling this method from my system tests, which are used for testing various endpoints:

```
private Product getProduct(name) {
    Response response = provider.target()
        .path(name)
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get();

    Product product = response.readEntity(Product.class);

    response.close();

    return product;
}
```

The function is simple removing a lot of clutter from my tests as well as calling `response.close()`. However, I would also like to return `response.getStatusInfo()` from this function as I am interested in both the data and the HTTP status code.

`response.close()` results in the methods `response.readEntity()` and `response.getStatusInfo()` no longer returning relevant information. How would you solve my problem?

I could do this:

```
private static class ProductRepsonse{
    StatusType statusType;
    Product product;
};
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: You could return the Response object. But maybe Retrofit library could help

Comment: @Baz, why do you mix method naming styles? Just use camel case for better consistency (`get_product` -> `getProduct`)

Comment: @cricket_007 But I close the response object in this method.

Comment: @Alex Nikolaenkov Fixed.

Comment: You also seem to have a block in http call with `get`, so that's not a good idea

Comment: @cricket_007 do you mean that get is sync?

Comment: Yes. In order for the following Product line to work, you need to wait synchronously for the Response to be received. Therefore blocking any other code. And so, I suggested Retrofit (because you have JSON)

Comment: @cricket_007 I will look into this thanks. Would you recommend this even in system tests?

Comment: Like unit testing? Not really. You'd want to mock your API service elsewhere.

Comment: @cricket_007 No, I am doing a system test where I call the backend and test the responses. In this example, get is used in the same manner as I use it: https://dzone.com/articles/test-your-jax-rs-20-web